# installed remote ceiling fan; light works; fan does not

Tags: ceiling-fan

I decided to install a remote ceiling fan in place of a standard fan myself.  The old fan was controlled by two wall switches (together).  I have a black, red and white wire in ceiling; but only a red and white wire coming from the remote receiver in the fan.  I wasn't sure to which I should wire the receiver but decided to match red to red and cap the black (suggested on youtube).

Fan all installed and looking nice. Turned breaker back on, but both wall switches in the "on"  position, and, for a moment was proud of myself.  pushed the button for the light and there was light!  Pushed the button for the fan and while there was a click sound, to my dismay, no movement of the fan! I'm guessing that the red wire from ceiling is for the light; the black for the fan, so should I have wired both black and red from ceiling to the red from the receiver?  I'm, obviously, not an electrician, but that seemed like it would be too much "heat" together.

Comment: Hello, and welcome  to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the inside of the switchbox, as well as of the connections at the fan? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes? Also, how attached are you to the remote kit that came with the fan, and are the two wall switches on the same "box space" (yoke/gang), or in separate box spaces?

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model # of the fan?

Comment: I am confused. How do you plan to control the fan? The switch, or the remote?